# CMake Error to install sr4000 camera (swissranger)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to run swissranger camera (sr4000) on ROS. I follow this tutorial http://visionlab.uncc.edu/dokuwiki/using_the_mesa_sr4000_with_ros_indigo

I installed the camera on Ubuntu properly. I tried to run it on ROS, but when I run this command (in the tutorial, in the step 3) "catkin_make", I got this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "driver_base" with
  any of the following names:

    driver_baseConfig.cmake
    driver_base-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "driver_base" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "driver_base_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "driver_base" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  open_ptrack/swissranger_camera/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/abbas/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/abbas/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,

Abbas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246755/cmake-error-to-install-sr4000-camera-(swissranger)/) by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're missing the driver_base package, and maybe a few other dependencies

You can install all of the dependencies for your workspace with:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
```

And then try to build again

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on 2016-10-30**:
Hi ahendrix,
Thank you for your reply. I installed all of the dependencies in my workspace with the codes that you mentioned. Then, I ran catkin_make, but I got the same error (that I mentioned before). I appreciate you for sharing any idea to solve this issue.
Thanks,
Abbas

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-10-30**:
rosdep should have installed the ros-kinetic-driver-base package, along with a bunch of other dependencies; did it? If you don't remember what rosdep installed, you can check that the package is installed with `dpkg -l ros-kinetic-driver-base`

**Comment by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on 2016-10-30**:
Hi ahendrix,
After running "rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y", I got "#All required rosdeps installed successfully" .After running "dpkg -l ros-kinetic-driver-base" I got "dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-driver-base". I am new in ROS. How can I install the package?
Thank you

**Comment by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on 2016-10-30**:
Hi ahendrix,
I installed the driver from https://github.com/ros-drivers/driver_common (for indigo). Then, catkin_make was ran without an error.
Thank you,
Abbas